# Send broadcast from C code

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, broadcast

I have a piece of C code (not an NDK app, plain C code),
and I am trying to send a broadcast to my app, 
but all I get is:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.example.A_NAME }
```

I never get the completed message.

The C code I am running is:

```
    char broadcast[200];
    sprintf(broadcast, "sh %s","com.example.A_NAME");
    FILE* pipe = popen(broadcast, "r");
    char buffer[128];
    char result[1500];
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            sprintf(result, "%s%s", result,buffer);
    }
    pclose(pipe);
```

For a simple bash script, I can get this working. From C, I tried `system()`, `execl()` etc, but nothing.

I also tried to put the command in a script file, and execute the script file.
If I execute the script from adb shell, it works. If I do it from C code, it does not work.

Comment: Apparently unrelated to your current problem, but to your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wasting a day, I got it working:

```
system("am broadcast -a com.example.DAMN_BROADCAST --user 0");
```

`--user 0`, thanks for wasting me a day.

**Note:**
All of the commands that I have tried should work. I 've written just the `system` command, since it is the easiest one and does the job (as long as you put `--user 0`). `execl`, `execlp`, and `pipes` should work as well.

Comment: I just tried you solution but no matter what is the command in system("...") I always get as ret value of the system call 32512. Any idea?